# How to select all href values on a page based on beginning text in URL?

Tags: javascript, dom, href

I have a webpage with hundreds of download links. The HTML for each of the download links looks like this:

```
<a href = 'viewlinks.php?regid=190404... '
```

Only after that last 0404 does each URL have unique numbers. I would like to select all of the href values on the page that start with `viewlinks.php?regid=190404`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Selecting all of the anchor elements on the page won't work because there are some href values that I don't want to select. Also there are no unique IDs or Classes for the download links I want.

Comment: `a[href^="value"]` is the starts with attribute selector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this in JS. Utilize with [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll).

```js
const links = document.querySelectorAll("a[href^='viewlinks.php?regid=190404']");

console.log(links);
```

```html
<a href='viewlinks.php?regid=1904041234'>1234</a>
<a href='viewlinks.php?regid=1904041222'>1222</a>
```